# Could not load file or assembly ### or one of its dependencies after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, nuget

My problem is that when I ran my project locally it worked just fine. But when I publish to my IIS server I get an error saying.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its
>   dependencies

When I fixed the Microsoft.Owin problem there was a problem with System.Web.Http.
Why is it only a problem after I publish?

Comment: are you using nuget packages to include those dll's?

Comment: Could you please tell the exact exception message you are getting including stack and source details.

Comment: @AndreiFilimon I'm using nuget

Comment: @KeertiSystematixInfotech Sure thing! http://pastebin.com/1mUY1f3t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason that I can't explain (please do if you know why) it worked to use my `web.release.config` instead of `web.debug.config`. I copied my entire `web.debug.config` to `web.release.config` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but a recent fix that I've found for this is if publishing from Visual Studio, to make sure that you select the option to remove all additional files at destination.  I upgraded my .NET framework, and it wasn't replacing the recompiled packages with the newer versions on Publish.

Answer (score 0):

Set your project References CopyLocal property to true.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in all of them at once?

Comment: I've gone through and set every reference to CopyLocal and it still doesn't work

Comment: Your application pool on the IIS server runs under same .NET framework as the referred dll's?

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the unvalid certificate in MyProject -> Properties -> Signing were I ticked "Sign the Assembly"

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue when deploying to an Azure App Service via Devops CI.

The fix was to restart the App service. Once it had JIT compiled after the first call to the web service, the error disappeared and it began working again as normal.